# is it possible to create a macro-like user defined shell command?

Tags: bash, command-line

Is it possible to run a single shortened command that would in turn initiate multiple longer to type commands?

for instance,

```
$ kontact & rekonq
```

when passed to my terminal opens two applications. Could I create a command of my own, to include this action and shorten the time it takes to perform it?

Comment: I've moved my answer from the other question as requested. In the future, please keep in mind you edit your question to clarify, instead of asking a new question. (Of course, it's best to have it clear from the start).

Comment: You can also do it with an alias or a shell function, both can be done interactively or added to your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a shell script. A shell script basically lets you turn anything you can type into the shell into a command. So, for example, to run those two programs from a shell, you'd run:

```
$ kontact &
$ rekonq &
```

To put those in a shell script, open a new file in a text editor, and put in the following lines:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
kontact &
rekonq &
```

You'll note that's very similar to what you typed in the shell—the only difference is that `#!/bin/bash` line up top (which the site has helpfully rendered in a different color for us). That line tells the system that this is a script that should be executed by bash.

Finally, after saving the file, you need to make it executable with `chmod +x file-name`.

Now, hypothetically, if you saved that as `/home/your-username/bin/run-my-programs` you could just type `~/bin/run-my-programs` into your shell, at both of those programs should start up.

Note that many distros have login scripts that will add a `bin` directory in your $HOME to your command search path automatically, so that is a great place to put shell scripts that you'd like to easily run. They will only do this, though, if `$HOME/bin` exists when you log in. Then you could leave out the path and just type `run-my-programs`. Obviously, you need to be careful naming your scripts so they don't conflict with other programs on your systems—it'd be confusing and surprising had you named that `ls`, for example!

---

The above shell script isn't really that useful. It's more useful when your programs are more complicated. For example, this is a real script I use at work:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

xterm -geometry 80x24+0+0 -T 'Bennu-DBA' -e ssh bennu -t 'screen -d -R -S status' &

xterm -geometry 80x24+0+342 -e screen -S 'bservers' -c ~/.screenrc-bservers &
xterm -geometry 80x9+0+684 -T 'df-graph' -xrm '.xterm.vt100.allowTitleOps: no' &

( cd ~/src/haruhi.metrics.net/operations/backup/bennu && xterm -geometry 80x24+0+827 -T 'Bennu-Conf' ) &
( cd ~/src/haruhi.metrics.net/operations/backup/phoenix && xterm -geometry 80x24+509+827 -T 'Bennu-Conf' ) &

xterm -geometry 177x77+509+0 -T 'Console' -e screen -c ~/.screenrc-bconsole  &
```

That saves a bunch of work manually placing and resizing windows (all those `-geometry` options). And all the `-e` options start up appropriate programs in them.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to create an *alias*?

```
$ alias macro="kontact & rekonq"
$ macro
```

Where *macro* is the name of your shortcut.

Comment: Creating an alias like this is only valid for the current shell session. It won't be available in new terminal windows, nor will it be available after logout / login. To keep it persistent, it needs to be added to the user account's dot-files, which based on the OP's other questions is a little bit too advanced for today.

Comment: @John, just add the line to your *~/.bashrc*. Then it will be available to any shell your user creates. Or even */etc/bash.bashrc* to make available to any user at your system.

Comment: That assumes you use the `bash` shell. If you use a different shell, `~/.bashrc` might not be valid.

Comment: Ok @John, add the line to *~/.profile* or */etc/profile* to be read by any interactive shell in a Unix like system. But just in case, check your shell's documentation for such specific constraints. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: i am using bash by the way, could you simplify that process for a noob lke myself? i dont know where to find bashrc

Comment: `~` is your home directory, so `~/.bashrc` is in your home directory. All files starting with a `.` are hidden. Use `-a` option to `ls` to see them i.e. `ls -a`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. this is quite common. Put the commands you wish to run into a text file, usually with a `.sh` extension (this is a convention, not necessary). You may have to `chmod +x <filename>`. Then you simply run `<filename>.sh` or `./<filename>.sh`. I usually create a `bin/` directory off my home directory for scripts like this.

Comment: Actually it is convention in Unix to not have a file extension. This makes it polymorphic: allows you to call from another script without knowing the implementation (you can change it to python, perl, or something else). If you have to change the file extension, then you have to change every script that calls it.

Comment: It's a convention in all the places I've ever worked to add a `.sh` extension. "Convnetion" is relative.

Comment: it will be fine with the extension, until it is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

One liner, append (with `>>`) the *alias* line in `.bash_profile`, so it stay available anytime, at reboot.

The `.` is to tell bash to reload (*source*) the configuration , and then `reset` makes those changes available in the current console.

`&&` means wait till command success, from left to right, so those commands aren't executed in parallel, but in sequential order.

---

```
echo 'alias macro="kontact & rekonq"' >> ~/.bash_profile && . ~/.bash_profile && reset
```

---

The you can immediately type in:

```
macro
```